# How I can hide text that is beetween special characters in Microsoft Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I'm trying to make a macro but I don't know where to start, I would like to hide some text between special chars like :

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ (including "space" char)
```

For example if I got a doc like this :

```
::00-58-96::Hello there
::00-58-97::This is a test
::00-58-98::Nothing else
::00-58-99::Good bye !
```

I would like to get this after the macro is executed :

```
Hello there
This is a test
Nothing else
Good bye !
```

The text between the

> :: ::

has been eliminated (including the :::)

Another example:

```
>>>some%text_here>>>This is another example
>>>some%text"here>>>Thank you for reading
>>>some%text@here>>>I hope you will have
>>>some&text²here>>>A great day
```

And the output will be :

```
This is another example
Thank you for reading
I hope you will have
A great day
```

At first time I was thinking on use the "Find and replace text" feature but I think is too complex for this.

Any hint will be really helpful.

Thanks !

Comment: So you only want alphabets out of the complete string ?

Comment: Note that "Find and replace" will strictly *replace* text, not *hide* it.

Comment: Please update your question to provide more example input/output. You've provided 4 example cases which all follow a *single* pattern. It's not clear (yet) what conditions you're trying to test for.

Comment: @Mikku no, I'm sorry, my example is not that descriptive, i want all the text (indifferently of alphabets/alphanumeric/special chars) between specified chars to be hidden.

Comment: @DavidZemens That's right, I was thinking of replace symbols/special chars with "   " but didn't work (have to try thought :) )

Comment: I don't think we can hide Text in Excel. But if you want it gone, then the below answer would suffice. @Satanas

Comment: @DavidZemens Maybe it's a bit clearer now :)

Comment: Is it always between *pairs* of special characters? In the second example you *open* with two > and *close* with three. How do we know that the `!` in the first example set should not be removed, since that's one of your special characters? I think I understand what you're trying to do, but I don't understand yet the rule(s) that you need to implement.

Comment: In other words, what is the general *pattern* you're trying to find? "Between special characters" is a starting point, but it's not enough to go on, e.g., would `Please don't!` turn into `Please don`? (because both the apostrophe and the exclamation form a boundary of special characters!).

Comment: @DavidZemens I'm sorry, bad editing, yes its always between pairs of symbols/special chars. The `!` wont be removed since there is no other ! in the paragraph. If there are impair chars between some text, the macro would just fail.

Comment: @Mikku Your macro was good :) I don't know why you deleted the answer. Thank you anyways

Comment: It wouldn't have solved your purpose... So I deleted it. Will post another answer, if i could find a logic.

Comment: I come to test your code with a tiny modification for my specific document and it works ! thank you to you 2 for your time ! Very reactive and nice community :)

Comment: @Satanas ... Undeleted my Answer. Glad it helped :)

Comment: Hello again :), I'm trying to make a macro to hide the text instead of placing him, but i cant actually use the Font.Hide property with your code. You got any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will Do:

## Note: It Will Delete the Text that is not required. Not Hide it.

```
Sub tst()

    ActiveDocument.Range.Select ' You can remove this line and run macro after selecting the text in which you want the replacement. This line will select the entire document.

With Selection.Find
     .MatchWildcards = True
     .Text = "::*::"
     .Replacement.Text = ""
     .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
     Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With


End Sub
```

*Pro: `Cntrl + Z` will work to undo this, if it doesn't perform as intended.*

Comment: Instead of replacing the text, change format to hidden? Also, add a parameter to the sub, so the "::" can be changed at will to something else (e.g. ">>>").

Comment: In curious too, how this macro should be to just hide the text instead of replacing?

Comment: @Satanas .... Why don't you just blend the text colour with Background... Would that work ??

Comment: with Background??? I don' know how to do it :s, it is this ? : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/word.document.background

Comment: I was trying to get back on this problem, still stuck lol, any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this - all you need is a single *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

Find = ([!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>\?@[\]^94_`{|}~]{2,})*\1

Then, depending on whether you want to delete or simply hide the found content, use:

Replace = nothing

or

Replace = ^&

with the 'Hidden' font property, respectively.

You could, of course, record the above as a macro.